# In Bassi Banner Slider Image is not uploading in magento?

Tags: magento

In Bassi Banner Slider, I'm going to upload an image in a slide. The image path has been stored to database, but the image is not uploading to site.
So image is not showing in front end, Only the path is shown.

What's the solution for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved....
All the images are coming from the amazon server and i was uploading it to testing server. 
On live site, it  works well.